# one label different color Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How to set a different color for one label?

```
label(for='middleName') Middle Name(optional)
```

What I want to do is that the "Middle Name" and "(optional)" will be black and grey respectively. How can I achieve this? Is there any way around it?

Note, I'm using pug template on HTML.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PUG

```
label(for='middleName') 
  span.black Middle Name
  span.grey (optional)
```

CSS

```
.black {
    color: black;
}
.grey {
    color: grey;
}
```